# Is it theoretically possible to create a 'window' to view behind a div using HTML and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently developing a page with a very large and focal background image which can move and will change depending on window size.

On top of this image I have a div with a solid colour and content.

Is it theoretically possible to set another div inside of this div and use it almost like a window to cut out the initial div to view the image underneath.

I would be happy if this utilised something that was only available in modern browsers.

If not I will have to cut up the initial div into 4 or so smaller divs and place them almost like a frame around the area I want to be able to look through, but I would like to try and achieve this as semantically as possible.

Any pointers in the right direction greatly received!

**What I have looked at**

I could be going down the wrong path here, but I am looking into how to mimic a type of screen capture, something like -> http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

I am thinking if I can manipulate this to take the picture only for the co-ordinates of the corners of the div and make it ignore the block colour div on top of it, I should be able to get the details and show them in a canvas element.

Then I would just need to make it update on drag,scroll and resize events.

**edit for clarification**

The content on the main div (with a solid background colour) has text and form elements that need to be clickable and useable.

Comment: Rather then having a solid colour and content have you tried using a border (and border images) ? And have the "window" part be the real transparent background

Comment: The content is text and form elements, I couldn't fake them I don't think.

Comment: @Toby, did you ever find a solution for "punching" through a div layer like this?

Comment: @BenRacicot- I used the PNG solution below, it isn't the prettiest thing in the world but it got the job done. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use a background image for your container div. The background image would be a PNG with a transparent square in the center. Please note that this would only work if your container div has a fixed width and height.

Comment: Sometimes the most simple solutions are the hardest to think up, this might just work, about to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using multiple gradient backgrounds, and pointer events. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CBRwM/embedded/result/) and a screenshot. Notice text can be selected due to `pointer-events` CSS property. My demo works only in Firefox right now, but can easily be ported to other browsers that support [multiple](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds) [gradient](http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient) backgrounds and [`pointer-events`](http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events). However, the `pointer-events` property affects the whole overlay, not just the hole which might be undesirable.

[image: div punch through].

And here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.underneath {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 265px 0 0 0;
  width: 600px;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px, transparent 150px, transparent),
              -moz-linear-gradient(0deg,   rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px, transparent 150px, transparent),
              -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px, transparent 150px, transparent),
              -moz-linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px, transparent 150px, transparent);
  pointer-events: none; /* send mouse events beneath this layer */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="underneath">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
  in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<div class="overlay"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woah, this is real progress from what I was looking at, thanks!

I just added a form element to the black content area though and it is not clickable/editable in Firefox 7.

Comment: @Toby It's because of `pointer-events`. Fiddle a bit with that property. You might change the value of this property (`auto`/`none`) on mouseover I guess. Mouse over hole, then `none`, mouse over form, then `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **opacity** in *css* for that *div*.

*for example :*

```
<style type="text/css">

#block
{
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

</style>

<div id="block">

This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.

</div>
```

Comment: Adding that to my new div would only show the div underneath it though. I need to dig deeper.