# Transparent hollow or cut out circle

Tags: css, svg, transparency, css-shapes

Is it possible to **cut out a hollow circle** using only *CSS*?

This we can all do:

[image: normal CSS circle]

But can we do this?

[image: transparent hollow circle in a div]

The **circle must be hollow and transparent**. Thus the problem is not solved by putting a solid color circle over a `div`.

Comment: By 'only CSS' presumably you prefer to not use images/[image-masks](http://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/)?

Comment: I want to do this, but using an element with a background-image and not only a plain color. Is that possible?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can achieve a **transparent cut out circle** with 2 different techniques :

### 1.SVG

The following examples use an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction). The first snippet uses the [mask element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask) to cut out the transparent circle and the second hollow circle is made with a [path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths). The circle is made with 2 [arc commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Arcs) :

**With the mask element :**

```css
body{background:url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 50" width="100%">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30">
      <rect x="5" y="5" width="90" height="40" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="50" cy="25" r="15" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0.7"/>    
</svg>
```

**With one path element :**

```css
body{background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');background-size:cover;}
svg{
  display:block;
  width:70%;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}
path{
  transition:fill .5s;
  fill: rgba(227, 223, 210, .8);
}
path:hover{
  fill:pink;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-10 -1 30 12">
  <path d="M-10 -1 H30 V12 H-10z M 5 5 m -5, 0 a 5,5 0 1,0 10,0 a 5,5 0 1,0 -10,0z"/>
</svg>
```

The main advantages of using SVG in this case are :

- Shorter code
- You can easily use an image or gradient to fill the circle mask
- maintain the boundaries of the shape and trigger mouse envents only over the fill respecting the mask (**hover the transparent cut out circle** in the example)

[image: transparent cut out circle]

### 2.CSS only using BOX-SHADOWS

Create a div with `overflow:hidden;` and a round pseudo element inside it with border-radius. Give it a huge box-shadow and no background :

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    width:500px; height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:175px; top:25px;
    border-radius:100%;
    width:150px; height:150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px #E3DFD2;
}

body{background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

*Browser support for box-shadows is IE9+ see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)*

The same approach would be to use border instead of box-shadows. It is interesting if you need to support browsers that don't support box-shadows like IE8. The technique is the same but you need to compensate with the top and left values to keep the circle in the center of the div :

```css
body{
    background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
div{
    position:relative;
    width:500px; height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:-325px; top:-475px;
    border-radius:100%;
    width:150px; height:150px;
    border:500px solid #E3DFD2;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for box-shadow, oh god why didn't i thought of that one! :/ i knew it that it can be done using some circle going out of border. but you nailed it!

Comment: Attention if using box-shadow in Safari.. they are not visible, but borders are. Use them instead.

Answer (score 32):

It can be done using a [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-radial-gradient) background and pointer-events (to allow mouse interaction behind through the circle layer, e.g. text selection). Here's [**a demo page**](https://jsfiddle.net/6xfy9zhn/1/) and a screenshot:

[image]

And this would be the code for it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.underneath {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 265px 0 0 0;
  width: 600px;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 150px);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 150px);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 150px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 150px);
  pointer-events: none;
  /* send mouse events beneath this layer */
}
```

```html
<body>

  <p class="underneath">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <div class="overlay"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: @chris You're welcome. If you're interested in a rectangle punch-through window, I've posted a similar answer a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979675/is-it-theoretically-possible-to-create-a-window-to-view-behind-a-div-using-htm/7980091#7980091

Comment: This however gives a circle with very "rough" edges, so if anybody has a solution that produces a nicely rendered punch-through circle it is highly welcome.

Comment: @chris if the size of the circle is fixed, then go with a centered background image, but keep the `pointer-events` part. If the size varies, then you can create masks out of SVG for WebKit https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-webkit-mask and Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content

Comment: @BenRacicot The fiddle isn't broken. See the copy paste here: http://output.jsbin.com/wibiyawawi

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan, thank you for answer. But can it be combined with image? So instead of black it will be masked with image?

Comment: This will only show a perfect circle if the underneath is square

Comment: Add `background: radial-gradient(circle at center,` to create a perfect circle regardless of underneath width/height

Answer (score 16):

Referring to web-tiki's answer I'd like to add that you can always center a div with `translate(-50%,-50%)`, so it'd be no problem to use the `border`-property, which has better browser support.

```css
div{
    position:relative;
    width:500px; 
    height:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius:50%;
    width:150px; height:150px;
    border: 1000px solid rebeccapurple;
}

body{background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can get really creative with this technique:

```js
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){ 
 setInterval(function(){
  if(document.getElementById("moving").style.height === "500px"){
   document.getElementById("moving").style.height = "0px";
  } else {  
   document.getElementById("moving").style.height = "500px";
  }
 }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#container {
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 overflow:hidden;
 position: relative;
}


#circle{
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    margin:0 auto;
 clear:left;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#circle::before, #circle::after {
    content:'';
    border-radius:50%;
 position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
#circle::before {
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    background: rebeccapurple;
}
#circle::after{
    width:150px; 
 height:150px;
    border: 2000px solid rebeccapurple;
}

#line {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 6px;
 height: 200px;
 position: relative;
}
#line::before, #line::after {
 content: " ";
 background-color: rebeccapurple;
    height: 200px;
 width:2000px;
 position:absolute;
}
#line::before {
 right: 100%;
}
#line::after { 
 left: 100%;
}

#moving {
 height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    transition: 2s height;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
body{
 background: url('https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8760/17195790401_ceeeafcddb_o.jpg');background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="circle"></div>
 <div id="line"></div> 
    <div id="circle"></div>
    <div id="moving"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For those who struggle with this like me - the div:after needs box-sizing: content-box; which is sometimes set to border-box by css frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding "Method 1" from "Pius Nyakoojo", with a minor improvement (see below) it would work. I personally think this is the simplest solution:

[image: screenshot]

```
<html>
<!-- Assuming the stuff to mask is a 100 pixel square -->
<style>
.mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;                     /* minus half the div size */
    left: -50px;                    /* minus half the div size */
    width: 100px;                   /* the div size */
    height: 100px;                  /* the div size */
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 100px;           /* the div size */
    border: 50px solid white;       /* half the div size */
    pointer-events: none;           /* send mouse events beneath this layer */
}

.stuff {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;                   /* the div size */
    height: 100px;                  /* the div size */
    overflow: hidden;               /* hide the excess of the mask border */
    background-color: #CCC;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="stuff">
        <div class="mask"></div>
        blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah
        blah blah blah blah blah
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

We can do this with `radial-gradient` and `mask`. With single div, no pseudo-element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1060/720/1280);
  background-size: cover;
}

.a {
  /* this is flexible. you can change */
  --circle-radius: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  --mask: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at center center, transparent var(--circle-radius), #000 calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px) 100%) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Circle radius can be percent value also:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1060/720/1280);
  background-size: cover;
}

.a {
  --circle-radius: 20%; /* changed as percent value */
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  --mask: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at center center, transparent var(--circle-radius), #000 calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px) 100%) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Another idea:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1060/720/1280);
  background-size: cover;
}

.a {
  --circle-radius: 100px;
  --border-width: 30px;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  --mask: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at center center, transparent var(--circle-radius), #000 calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px) calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px + var(--border-width)), transparent calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px + var(--border-width) + 2px) 100%) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Reverse:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1060/720/1280);
  background-size: cover;
}

.a {
  --circle-radius: 100px;
  --border-width: 30px;
  
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  --mask: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at center center, #000 var(--circle-radius), transparent calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px) calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px + var(--border-width)), #000 calc(var(--circle-radius) + 2px + var(--border-width) + 2px) 100%) 50% 50%/100% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
```

Comment: This solution worked well for my use case, as percentage sizing was a hard requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1- **Preferred**

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

```
$radius: 50px;
$thickness: 5px;

.circle {
    width: $radius;
    height: $radius;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: $radius;
    border: $thickness solid gray;
}
```

Method 2

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

```
$radius: 50px;
$thickness: 5px;

.circle {
  width: $radius;
  height: $radius;
}

.circle::before, .circle::after {
  margin: -2px 0;
}
.circle::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: $radius;
    height: calc(#{$radius} / 2);
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top-left-radius: calc(#{$radius} / 2);
    border-top-right-radius: calc(#{$radius} / 2);
    border: $thickness solid gray;
    border-bottom: 0;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.circle::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: $radius;
  height: calc(#{$radius} / 2);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(#{$radius} / 2);
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(#{$radius} / 2);
  border: $thickness solid gray;
  border-top: 0;

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't method 1 just create a border? The whole area outside the circle should be coloured. Not just the border.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using css masks and extra svg image.
[Although browser support is weak](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks)

[image: ![enter image description here]

```css
body {
  background: url(https://data.whicdn.com/images/50959200/original.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask: url(https://svgshare.com/i/GLf.svg);
  -webkit-mask-size: 125%; /* change it */
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```