# What is best way to make half circle negative CSS border radius div mask?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Now days I see many themes using triangle/arrow mask that is placed over a div

[image]

you can see it [here](http://canary.is/) over the video

But I would like to do a inverted ( negative ) border radius if possible, that forms a **half circle** , kinda like this

[image]

I was almost there with radial gradient but it just looks edgy in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/2457/

```
.haflcircle {
    background:
        -moz-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(0,0,0,0) 25px, #000 25px),
        -moz-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(0,0,0,0) 25px, #000 25px);
    background:
         -o-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(0,0,0,0) 25px, #000 25px),
         -o-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(0,0,0,0) 25px, #000 25px);
    background:
         -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 0, circle, rgba(0,0,0,0) 25px, #000 25px),
         -webkit-radial-gradient(0 0, circle, rgba(0,0,0,0) 25px, #000 25px);
}

.haflcircle {
    background-position: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left;
    -moz-background-size: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

it would be great if you know a better way to do this.

**Found suitable solution with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503636/transparent-half-circle-cut-out-of-a-div) 
It also works with transparent colors 
http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/2465/ thnx for helping**

Comment: @Vucko it would be great if you can show an example.

Comment: I make just little changes. For `-moz-radial-gradient` last value increased to `26px` and `height:52px;`, if that's acceptable for You. There is filddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/2461/

Comment: @Benn take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758922/transparent-arrow-triangle. Than just change `background-color` to `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);`, for 1 example and you will get [this](https://jsfiddle.net/x2zktv1L/).

Comment: thnx for it but it just looks bad , see this, http://prntscr.com/8cb80j  chrome

Comment: @AleshaOleg looking for half circle , not triangle http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/2457/

Comment: yeah... You're right... I test on FF.

Comment: @Benn: There are a lot of methods discussed in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503636/transparent-half-circle-cut-out-of-a-div/30726390#30726390) that you may want to have a look at.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty easy to do without having to mess with radial gradients and such.

Just make sure the left position of the half circle is 50% - 1/2(width of half circle) , and top position is -1/2*height of half circle.

```css
#topdiv {
    height: 50px;
    background: lightblue;
}
#bottomdiv {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
#halfcircle {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    left: 47%;
    background: lightblue;
    border-radius: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="topdiv"></div>
<div id="bottomdiv">
    <div id="halfcircle"></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuzxzzpL/1/)

Comment: cant do that bud , look at this scenario where bg is an image or video
http://jsfiddle.net/xuzxzzpL/2/   that circle must be transparent ,

Comment: If you can figure out how to synchronize the position of the bg Image, then this approach would work. Could be complicated?

Answer (score 3):

I used `clip-path` in SVG to cut out the circle. You need to define the circle as a path, otherwise you won't be able to invert the clip. In my example, the circle is 80px wide.

SVG

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <defs>
      <clipPath id="circleClip">
         <path d="M0,0H100V100H-100zM5,0a40,40 0 1,0 80,0a40,40 0 1,0 -80,0"/>
      </clipPath>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

The d attribute shows two paths, the first one, being a rectangle, and the second one the circle to cut out of it. I also tried using `clip-rule="evenodd"`, but that did not really work for me.

Use it like this in your CSS:

```
-webkit-clip-path: url(#circleClip);
clip-path: url(#circleClip);
```

Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/h2stx2L8/1/

Comment: would love to use it but support for it is bad  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path