# CSS round shape inside block

Tags: html, css

I need to set shape in the middle of the block.

What i need

[image]

There is `liniar-gradiend circle` in css, but it's hard to work with response, because it sets with px.

Is it any way to do this thing in css?

Comment: Related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913730/css-cut-out-circle-from-a-rectangular-shape/36914130#36914130?

Comment: Please provide us with some code so we can try to help you!