# How to make these unusually cut corners?

Tags: css, layout

How do I make these corners? Guess I can use pseudo elements but I can't figure out how it's exactly done

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NVJ5.png)

What I tried to do:

```
<div class="div"></div>
```

```
.div {
  width: 415px;
  height: 241px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background-color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  borde-bottom-left-radius: 0;
/*   z-index: 2; */
}

.div::before {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 55px;
  bottom: -1px;
  border-radius: 60%;
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 0 0 white;
}
```

Comment: Probably a clip path but this is related in all liklihood. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913730/css-cut-out-circle-from-a-rectangular-shape