# Create a full width semi circle with a div and radial gradient

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate the following footer design that uses a full width semi circle.

[image]

I'm attempting this simply with a radial-gradient background for my footer:

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center bottom, #387546, #387546 50%,transparent 50%);
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```

Here is the result I get:
[image]

How can I modify my radial-gradient to achieve this? Or is there a better method of getting the desired effect? (I'm just looking for the green semi-circle part of the design)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913730/css-cut-out-circle-from-a-rectangular-shape

Comment: I'm asking about the green circle, not the white cut-out.

Comment: As asked (but not answered) in my comment to your previous version of this question - how is the height that is to show defined? If it is 30vh as in the code here, what happens on portrait viewports where the width may be less? And previously you said the width was 100% of body - can we assume that is always 100vw?

Comment: Body can easily be greater than 100vw wide if it depends on content. My questions were genuine as you had not put in the additional constraint that a height of 30vh would always be able to accommodate <= a semi circle. Don’t assume we don’t know anything when we ask for more info!

Comment: The question regarding `height: 30vh` is perfectly valid as footer might not fit content because of this. Also `body` can have any `width` more or less 100vw and by default it's definitely not 100vw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might play with gradient size and position, and background size and position:

```css
footer {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(100% 120vh at 50% calc(100% + 30vh), #387546 calc(50% - 2px), #38754600 50%) 50% / calc(100% + 60vh) 100%;
    height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple syntax

```css
footer {
  --r: calc(30vh + 80vw); /* the radius (update like you want) */
  
  background: radial-gradient(var(--r) at 50% var(--r), #387546 calc(100% - 1px), #0000);
  height: 30vh;
  
  min-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```