# Multiple U shapes divs

Tags: css

I'm trying to obtain some nice U shapes divs.
This is the expected result (it must look nice and be responsive):
[image]

This is the solution I found for footer (the shape is not so good as I want):

```
footer:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: white; /* but if I choose a bg image for about us this solution is wrong */
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
}
```

I will have multiple sections similar to `#about-us`. Can you suggest a nice starting solution here? Please keep in mind in brand section background I have an animation, in footer a background image. This is why I can't use in `about-us` the solution I used for `footer`. It's kind of let's cut this div with an oval and make this section transparent.

UPDATE:
My current header / about us annoying merge. Adding a gray shape (inside header or in top of about us) is not a solution.
[image]

Comment: You're probably going to need a `clip-path` if you are planning on a background image showing through.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. I will check these solutions, too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503636/transparent-half-circle-cut-out-of-a-div Seems to be the same task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.u-shape {
  height: 120px;
  right: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.u-shape.top {
  top: -120px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 0, transparent 69%, white 70%);
}

.u-shape.bottom {
  top: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 0, white 69%, transparent 70%);
}
```

Usage:

```
<header>...</header>
<div class="u-shape top"></div>
<div id="about-us"></div>
<div class="u-shape bottom"></div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

Useful:
https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/wFvmA