# CSS, Clip inner circle to image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, banner

I'm trying to use a "clip path" on an image with a rounded bottom section. I try with  svg clip paths, but the cut it's a outer circle ,i don't know if is the best approach because the clip is outer and not inner what do you recommend to achieve this?

[I want to achive this ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgavb.png)

This is the codepen where i try to make it:

```css
.section-test {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/ddioeulgw/image/upload/v1548437500/test/hero.png);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 85vh;
  clip-path: ellipse(85% 100% at 50% 0%);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-test">

</section>
```

https://codepen.io/kenmarquez-the-typescripter/pen/ombege

[I want to achive this ->](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgavb.png)

Comment: Oh, that code is just a hack to get the code pen link..... Stackoverflow has snipplets which allows you to paste your actual code into the post and have it run.

Comment: I edited it to have the HTML/CSS so you do not get pinged....

Comment: @epascarello thank's do you know how to show the banner image that i want to achive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503636/transparent-half-circle-cut-out-of-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it: I would use an SVG element. The clipPath have `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and the path have all it's values between 0 and 1.

```css
svg{position:absolute}
.section-test {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/ddioeulgw/image/upload/v1548437500/test/hero.png);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 85vh;
  clip-path: url(#clip); 
  }
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" >
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
           <path d="M0,0 L0,.5 A1,1 0 0  1 1,.5 L1,0 0,0" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
 
<section class="section-test">
</section>
```

I hope it helps.

> **clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"**: This value indicates that all coordinates inside the  element are relative to the bounding box of the element the clipping path is applied to. It means that the origin of the coordinate system is the top left corner of the object bounding box and the width and height of the object bounding box are considered to have a length of 1 unit value.

*MDN quote*