# Create curved speech bubble tail

Tags: html, css

How can I create the white background shape in the following image using pure CSS?

[image: speech bubble shaped element]

I'm already able to achieve the top-left and bottom-right curved corners using `border-radius`, so I am specifically talking about the pointy "tail" shape in the bottom-left corner.

I was hoping to be able to use a pseudo element with some kind of cool `border-radius` or `clip-path` trick to create the shape rather than having to resort to using an SVG background on the pseudo element.

Has anyone got a way to do this with pure CSS?

The element appears multiple times on different coloured backgrounds so the "cut out" curved part of the tail needs to be transparent.

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8503928/3956676) with some slight tweaks helps achieve this. Basically what they did is make a circle with a big border and then they cut off the undesired parts. If you move the circle around you can make the inverted circle kind of effect as you described.

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.rect {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0px;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -100px;
  border: 40px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-right: 40px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.overflow {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">&nbsp;<span class="circle"></span></div>
<div class="rect">&nbsp;<span class="circle overflow"></span></div>
```