# To use knockout css class to hide text and knockout image overlay?

Tags: css, overlay, parallax

Apologies if the question is a little vague.

I have basic css skills.

I'm trying to hide the text, but use it to knockout the image overlay. So when scrolling, the "text" is generated by the underlying image due to the parallax.

I've tried

-webkit-text-color:transparent;
-webkit-background-clip:text;

but knew that'd be a long shot because I don't know  how to apply it to the overlay using the text.

http://ochreand.blue/home/#top-1

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242806/hole-in-overlay-with-css

Comment: Thanks so much Roy J. One of the links in that thread looks exactly like what I'm after.