# Can I use an image as a mask?

Tags: html, css

Can I make a regular image to  mask element lying beneath it? For example I want a `div` element with background image with hole inside it, which will hide all elements which lying beneath it, except elements beneath the hole. Found the following example https://stackoverflow.com/a/8286622/947111 how to do this with plain color, but I doubt is it possible to replace black color by image?

P.S. Of course solution should work while page being resized.

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.underneath {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 265px 0 0 0;
  width: 600px;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(transparent 150px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 150px);
  pointer-events: none; /* send mouse events beneath this layer */
}
```

```html
<p class="underneath">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
  in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Image is a bit big but here you go. Just use a transparent PNG with transparency where you want your hole. then set the background to an image rather than a radial gradient.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.underneath {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 265px 0 0 0;
  width: 600px;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: url('http://www.genericorp.net/~vostek/images/circlemask-1024x768.png');
  background-size: 600px 600px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  pointer-events: none; /* send mouse events beneath this layer */
}
```

```html
<p class="underneath">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
  in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Is this solution resizable?

Comment: That is the issue with using an image vs vector graphics, they have to be scaled.  Either create different variations of the image and switch them out depending on resolution or you can live with the potential pixelation just use percents for sizes and it will scale with the page.

Comment: I do not know why this answer got a down vote. Your original question did not ask about responsive. You have a hard width and height on the overlaying DIV, so in your answer - no, this is not responsive.

Comment: I didn't downvoted it, but I'll update my answer to reflect this issue

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.underneath {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 265px 0 0 0;
  width: 600px;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(http://seanrawles.work/test/Aerial_view_Sausalito-example.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  pointer-events: none; /* send mouse events beneath this layer */
}
```

```html
<p class="underneath">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
  in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Well it seems to work.

Comment: Try to stay away from `background-size`

Comment: If you'd like it to be responsive, you need to eliminate the static pixels. See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/scoopzilla/pen/YNxPjE)

Comment: Wow, but I quite don't understand where do you define a circle inside? How can I change its size and x,y location?

Comment: I didn't. Same answer as the other, using a PNG. However it does **SEEM** possible - here is another answer that is similar: [Hole in Olverlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242806/hole-in-overlay-with-css) but the example does say it is not compatible on all browsers.

Comment: This might be a good place to start. I have never used them so I cannot speak to their effectiveness: [CSS3 Masking Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually surprised, but I got it working with `mask-image` which is [quite widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks). There are a few gotchas but one of the most interesting things I'm doing is creating a black to black image gradient as part of the composition instead of a second image. Thus, in the end, this solution uses only 1 image, that of a white `png` circle.

Besides your own set pixel sizes, all of mine use percentages to maintain responsiveness.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.underneath {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 265px 0 0 0;
  width: 600px;
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: #000;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(black 0%, black 100%), url(http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/circle-xxl.png);
  mask-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  mask-position: center center, center center;
  mask-composite: source-out;
  mask-size: 100%, 60%;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(black 0%, black 100%), url(http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/circle-xxl.png);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center center, center center;
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-out;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%, 60%;
  pointer-events: none; /* send mouse events beneath this layer */
}
```

```html
<p class="underneath">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt
  in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: I do not see a result in the snippet.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Ah, apparently it's not fully supported in FireFox. There's workarounds but let me know if you care enough to see them. I'm just going to leave as is, if you're going with another answer.

Comment: Safari and CHrome, no box.

Comment: Works for me on both. Oh well, it was fun.

Comment: CSS IS fun! Maybe it's somethign on my end. Dunno.