# overlay with transparent square inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

right now I have something like the following as seen below. I want the square to be transparent, meaning there is an "overlay" effect for the background, but a transparent square so I can view the items below it.

May I ask if this is possible to implement?

```css
.overlay{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.square{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid lime 1px;
  background-color: transparent !important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a transparent "hole" i the `div.overlay` where the square is ?

Comment: yes.. meaning that the square would be a transparent part of the overlay

Comment: Use `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);` on the square

Answer (score 1):

Just use a giant `box-shadow` like this -

```css
.overlay{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.square{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid lime 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px red;

}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

In fact you don't need  the square div at all if you use an inset box-shadow

```css
.overlay {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae saepe hic sequi eveniet iusto est corrupti commodi porro! Dignissimos provident voluptas numquam iste corrupti at?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is an interesting solution !

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible, you can use the new `clip-path` CSS property, or `box-shadow`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242806/hole-in-overlay-with-css)'s answers for some examples, they are really great !

Comment: Thank you! will look it up, had some issues finding a similar topic on SO and decided to post after many failed search attempts...

Comment: @Max no problem, but please do not forget to accept the answer that helped you the most (does not have to be mine, of course) !

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.