# Build a rectangle frame with a transparent circle using CSS only

Tags: html, css, image

I need to implement a design to my webpage butI am kind of newbie with CSS.

What I am trying is to add a frame above the user picture. For example, for any size of image, I want that a given profile image like:

[image]

... I want to add a rectangle with a transparent circle inside like:
[image]

... so the final result would be like:

[image]

I am currently adding this frame as an image an resizing the user's image but it decreases resolution.

I really need the frame height size to be equal the image height size and put a frame and circle according to the user image.

Any Ideas?

Comment: why not make the image circular with css and put in a div?

Comment: for transparent circle you can also check out this question : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26481923/1811992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are 2 ways:
1)
HTML:

```
<div class="profile_pic_cont">
   <img src="img/profile_pic.jpg" class="profile_pic" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile_pic_cont {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #d2e8f7; /* light blue */
padding: 5px;
}
.profile_pic {
border-radius: 9999px;
}
```

or
2)
HTML:

```
<div class="profile_pic_cont">
   <img src="img/profile_pic_frame.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile_pic_cont {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: #fff url('./img/profile_pic.jpg') no-repeat top left;
```

}

Comment: Wouldn't create transparent background for image in both cases.

Comment: Although you didn't created the transparent background, it was the best and cleaner implementation. It gets to the same result but with less effort, Cheers matey!

Answer (score 4):

Here try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/6hFcj/)**. To check transparency, try changing body color.

```
<div class="outerCont">
    <div class="innerCont centerAlign">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjDS6.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.outerCont{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.innerCont{
    background-color:transparent;
    border:150px solid rgb(186, 230, 255);
    border-radius:50%;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.innerCont img{
    position:absolute;
    height:80%;
    bottom:0;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%);
}
.centerAlign{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

HERE IS THE [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/nG8NF/2/)

```
.circle {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px; 
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/NGz1YlF.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:65%;
    background-position:center bottom;
}
```

Comment: But that is with white background and not transparent;

Comment: Giving it background with opacity 0 still wouldn't work. It would just show `background-color` for `.box`  here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/nG8NF/3/)

Comment: exactly I was trying hard to solve it, do you have any soulution for this, because there are 3 layers, background, box and circle,I think I  need to create a square with hole, but with the box model I dont how to create it without using image

Comment: Ha! but I guess OP didn't care for that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should draw the square, then the circle on top of it and finally put the image, this will produce the result you want.
Check [there](http://www.cardeo.ca/how-to-create-circles-with-css3-and-no-images/) for how to trace a circle in CSS.

Comment: That's right but it wouldn't exactly create the results what he wants.