# Creating a viewhole or round circle into an element with background image to see through?

Tags: jquery, css

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

a sidebar that slides in, so it is not only one still image but an animation.
Trick is: it is not one color, but the background image used in the sidebar is a blurred image of the sharp background image. If you scroll down, I scroll the position of the blurred background image along, so it gives this blurry lense effect.

People afterwards can scroll down and the viewhole should adjust. The only solution I can think of is duplicate the background image in front of the slidebar in an element as a circle, and scroll this accordingly as well. It feels like an overkill. Is there no better solution?

I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-circle-using-only-css#) but it does not seem that there is a way to allow background images.

Comment: a hack will be to make the bg of the circle as the body bg and the positon of the picture is changed with jquery