# How to create a mask over an image (not a clip-path, but the opposite)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mask

I'm trying to apply a mask to a div so I can see through it to a background image. Everything I'm seeing is about clip-paths, but I am looking for the opposite of this. Clip-paths show what is in the inside of the clip. I'm trying to have it be a mask, so that you see the outside of the clip.

[Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcvMv.jpg), and below is a full description of the example.

I have a div with a background image. Inside this div is another div that covers the full width and height of its parent (with the background image), and has a semitransparent (rgba) background color. I'm trying to add a mask to this overlay div (the one with the rgba background color) so that a circle is cut out of the middle that shows the full background image without the color overlay.

[Here is a link to a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bluebomber/yjx2phk6/) that sets up what I am talking about, but without the mask (since I don't know how to do it).

```
<div class="backgroundImage">
  <div class="backgroundOverlayWithMask">
    <!-- content will be here -->
  </div>
</div>

.backgroundImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/New_york_times_square-terabass.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover
}

.backgroundOverlayWithMask {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: i would create a bitmap image mask, like a png or gif.

Comment: I really need a crisp responsive solution to this issue that will work on standard and retina screens. The edges of the mask would get fuzzy/blurry at different screen sizes if I used an image mask.

Comment: regardless, afaik, there's no standard way of achieving what you want with just css... i also don't think a crisp hi-res geometric shape would alias too bad, fwiw

Comment: I'm not looking for a "just css" solution. This could be css, javascript, svg, or all of the above. I've seen that svg has a <mask> tag, but I haven't found a way to get it to work. Thank you though!

Comment: well, i guess you could generate the mask with a canvas on the fly, then export to a data/blob url you can feed CSS with. a simple circle should be easy to get running with w3fools code...

Comment: That's definitely a good try. I was playing around with options like that for a bit, but the two background images don't always line up properly because of the responsiveness. I've come to the realization that I need a true mask.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution using `box shadow`, `:after`, and `flex`.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kovuvcnj/3/).  Based on web-tiki's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-circle-using-only-css).

```css
#inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#inner:after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  align-self: center;
}
#container {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/800x200');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool. Seems to be working in Chrome just fine, but not in Safari. I'll have to look into making this work across all browsers. Thanks!

Comment: @bluebomber check out the webkit extensions I added to the answer for safari.

Comment: @lamelemon still doesn't seem to be working in Safari

Comment: @bluebomber tbh I don't have a Mac or anyway to test in Safari.  Is the box shadow showing at all or what exactly is happening?

Comment: @lamelemon I was able to get the mask to show on all desktop browsers by doing this:  


`-webkit-appearance: none;  
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);  
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);  
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);`  

You'll see that I added a 10px to only the box-shadow property. Now, I'm just not able to get it to work in iOS, but I'm looking into it.

Comment: I just had to change the one box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); to box-shadow: 0px 0px 2000px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75); and it is working in Safari for both desktop and mobile. Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: @bluebomber awesome.  Glad to be of help!