# "Overflow: hidden" doesn't hide children on Iphone

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow

I've created a div-circle in which I want to hold (1) an image and (2) three div-waves (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyc9m.png)). My solution is working on desktop with Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer. However, on my iPhone, the overflow doesn't work at all, either in safari or chrome. [Here's an image of the difference in result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyc9m.png). The relevant HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="circleContainer">
    <div class="wavesContainer">
        <div class="wave1" />
        <div class="wave1" />
        <div class="wave1" />
    </div>

    <img />
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS code looks like this:

```css
.circleContainer {
    border-radius: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #232323;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: #404040 solid 4px;
    background-image: URL("pathToBackgroundImage");
    background-size: 300px;
    background-position: -20px;
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.wavesContainer {
    transition: .5s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.wave1,
.wave2,
.wave3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
}

.circleContainer img {
    height: 220px;
    top: 28px;
    left: 18px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .5s;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**NOTE:** The HTML and CSS are simplified, but I think the code above is all that is necessary to solve this issue.

Here is the code if you want to see it for your self: https://github.com/rrudling/rudling-tech/tree/main/src/components/pages/HomePage/ImageAnimation and here is the live demo: https://rudling-tech.web.app/

I am pretty experienced with CSS and still nothing I've tried work, so you guys are my last hope. I appreciate all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a rather brute-force solution. Namely to create a rectangular shape (the red one in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLYD2.png)) with a transparent circle cut, as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-hollow-or-cut-out-circle) thread. I could then hard code some of the z-indices such that the rectangle only hides what I want it to. I also added a new circle with a border (the green one in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLYD2.png)) so I could keep the border around the circle.

It wasn't the solution I was hoping for, but it fully solved my problem!