# Make a block inside a div transparent to the image behind

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create this effect where the block inside the div is transparent to the image behind

here's a image of what i'm trying to accomplish  https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0FlJ.png

the problem here is I don't know how to make it transparent since the block is taking the white background if I put a `background-color: transparent` to the block, I tried with some z-index with no success because the image still goes in front of the section

here's my html

```
        <div class="bg">
            <div class="block">
                <h1 class="block__title">Rock climbing in Yosemite</h1>
                <div class="block__transparent"></div>
                <p class="block__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et...</p>
            </div>               
        </div>
```

sorry if I didn't explain well my problem, I tried to be as simple as possible

Comment: I believe this existing post may answer the question: [Transparent hollow or cut out circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-hollow-or-cut-out-circle)