# How can I punch holes through an element to see the background image below?

Tags: css

I want to make an element look like a plaque by “drilling holes” near its corners so that the background image will be visible behind.

[image: a rounded square with holes in the corners]

The element is responsive, so it can be portrait, square or landscape, but as its shape adjusts, the holes in its corners need to remain circular. The size of the holes should be responsive, though — preferably proportional to `vmin`.

This snippet is my starting point.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/167/1000);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100svh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 7vmin;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  border-radius: 4vmin;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">Roses are red,<br>violets are blue.</div>
```

I know I could get close with an SVG background image, or with an SVG mask, but neither of these solutions allow the holes to stay circular.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/167/1000);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100svh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 7vmin;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  color: white;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  border-radius: 4vmin;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;

  -webkit-mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><circle cx="15" cy="15" r="5"/><circle cx="185" cy="15" r="5"/><circle cx="15" cy="185" r="5"/><circle cx="185" cy="185" r="5"/></svg>') 0/100% 100%, linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;

  mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none"><circle cx="15" cy="15" r="5"/><circle cx="185" cy="15" r="5"/><circle cx="15" cy="185" r="5"/><circle cx="185" cy="185" r="5"/></svg>') 0/100% 100%, linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
  mask-composite: exclude;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">Roses are red,<br>violets are blue.</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent hollow or cut out circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286550/transparent-hollow-or-cut-out-circle)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a radial gradient coloration. No need for mask

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/167/1000);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100svh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.d1 {
  --r: 2vmin; /* radius */
  color: white;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 60vh;
  border-radius: calc(2*var(--r));
  border: var(--r) solid goldenrod; /* the outer space*/
  background: 
   radial-gradient(var(--r) at var(--r) var(--r),#0000 98%,goldenrod)
   0 0/calc(100% - 2*var(--r)) calc(100% - 2*var(--r));
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works very well, but I’d be very grateful if you could provide an explanation of how it works.

Comment: It's okay, I figured it out. You use a radial gradient to create a single hole, then you repeat that gradient in both dimesions so that we end up with four holes. The first part of the radial gradient expression specifies the size and origin of the hole relative to the background. The second part says the hole is fully transparent (#0000) from the origin to 98% of the radius, then the third part is transition to goldenrod (100% is implied). The next part of the expression is the position/size of the background itself, with the size being calculated as 100% minus double the gradient radius.

Comment: ... so with the size being just a bit smaller than 100%, this allows the background to repeat in both dimensions, resulting in four holes in the corners. Very nifty.

Comment: What makes this solution so nifty is that the radial gradients which create the holes are sized relative to the viewport (using `vmin` units), whereas the background tile which contains the gradient (hole) and which repeats to multiply them is sized relative to the (responsive) element. Perfect.